# How to try a hardware and software combination in advance? (Getting an old printer to work on newer hardware.)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I am trying to get an old printer [driver](https://epson.com/Support/Printers/Single-Function-Inkjet-Printers/Epson-Stylus-Series/Epson-Stylus-Color/s/SPT_C137001) (for an "Epson Stylus Color" [their first hi-res printer, hence no trailing model number]) to work on newer equipment. It works under 32-bit Windows XP running on a 32-bit Intel Pentium 4 processor. It won't install under 32-bit Windows 7 running on a 64-bit AMD quad-core processor. But I suspect that if I had 32-bit Windows 7 running on a 64-bit Intel quad-core processor, it would install because I see that the Windows XP driver properties show "Intel".

Is there some way I can simulate/try, or find/enlist someone to try, this combination in advance so that I don't have to BUY such a machine just to find out whether it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a driver for your current OS, you are out of luck. Windows 7 offers XP mode, install that then install the XP printer driver in XP mode>>>>>>[microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8002](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8002)

Comment: I see.  Do you know of a way to get the Host OS to be able to send print jobs to the Guest OS/Virtual-XP Mode?